# Using a custom version tag pattern\vcs path in composer.json

Tags: php, composer-php

I have an svn* repo that contains a collection ("MyCommonLib") of libraries eg src\LibA, src\LibB etc.

I would like to publish each Lib* as separate composer package. I've included a composer.json in each Lib* and I can point composer at each trunk\src\Lib* and it doesn't seem to mind that.... until versions are involved.

The tag structure is versioned for the whole collection `tags\1.0\composer.json`, which is fine per se for the collection (MCL) . However, this is not fine for Lib* as the MCL\composer.json != MCL\src\LibA\composer.json.

*Ideally* I "simply" want to spec in the LibA\composer.json that its "tag versions" are pulled from a specified path. I.e. `tags\[version]\src\LibA\composer.json` instead of the bog standard `tags\[version]\composer.json`

Is there anyway to do this?

*While SVN will always be in the picture, I have the ability to setup git mirrors if that helps *at all*.

PS This may smell like [Using Composer when multiple components are in the same vcs repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946482/using-composer-when-multiple-components-are-in-the-same-vcs-repo) but its A) been 6 *years* on and B) I'm specifically asking about the tag\version pattern discovery having solved the basic package discovery its self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `package-path` settings to specify path of package inside of repository:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://svn.example.org/",
        "package-path": "src/LibA/"
    }
]
```

Composer should use `https://svn.example.org/trunk/src/LibA/composer.json`, `https://svn.example.org/branches/[branch name]/src/LibA/composer.json` and `https://svn.example.org/tags/[version]/src/LibA/composer.json` as a paths for this package.

See [example in documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#subversion-options).

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work in our environment. Our repo layout (how we got it to "work", but not live in trunk) is causing errors on package submission. I think we're back to making it monolithic. However, your answer is technically correct, which is the best kind of correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but you should be able to change trunk path by `trunk-path` setting.

Comment: So the short of it is that discovery is a problem again. I'll go into detail, in case there's a lone soul in the same boat. We had "chunked" out the individual libs from svn to github (each in thier own gh repo using subgit). This granted us ease of maintenance (mono in svn) + discovery (packagist could read "trunk/master" on GH) but no version\tags since they were not sent to GH. Turns out our subgit was either old or misconfigured as I *just* got it to send "chunked" tags too. https://subgit.com/documentation/branches-mapping.html#multiple_projects